# JQuery Mobile Navbar is bugging

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I want to make a Navbar with JQM, the system is adding unnecessary `&nbsp` into the grid, which makes the navbar look weird.

I am using JQM 1.4.5 and Jquery 1.11.2.

Code:

```
<div id="home" data-role="page">
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For people who are seeing this and having the same problem: If you copy the code for the widgets from the JQuery Mobile Demos, there are spaces between the tags which you will see in the browser. Delete them and it should look normal again.

Comment: try to double-click this black window... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Having the second tab dropped blow like that maybe caused by your css. Try using display: inline-block or even floats to get those items to align correctly.

Comment: It was because my editor doesn't show blank spaces. It happens when you double click the demo source codes and copy-paste it. Took me several hours to find it out. It's like finding the missing semicolon in your code. Very frustrating.